# error installing Python lineprofiler

Tags: python, pip

I have a problem installing lineprofiler for Python.

I've tried `pip install --pre line_profiler`, but it doesn't work.

It given following error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

line_profiler is implemented in C via Cython in order to reduce the overhead of profiling.

vcvarsall.bat is part of the Microsoft Visual Studio toolset and is used to compile the C extensions.

If you don't want to compile the C extensions yourself, you can download the compiled Windows binary(.exe) from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/l/line_profiler/line_profiler-1.0b3.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=5291b022cc675a335c2813458ec8e7ad), and install it.

Comment: I've tried to do it but the exe doesn't find my Python version installed, so I can't install it